# matplotlib svg save - light borders around contourf levels

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, save, export

The following code is taken in part from the contour demo of the matplotlib documentation. I am using contourf instead of simple contour. The contour plot is shown just as I want it to be within the matplotlib figure window.

As soon as it comes to saving I am not content with the result. A PNG save looks perfect, but I do not have any levels, as png si no vector format. When saving to PDF of SVG format I have levels, BUT there are thin light borders around the levels. At first I thought they are caused, because every level is getting a stroke around. When opening the SVG file with inkscape to drop those strokes, I found out, that actually the levels are saved just a bit to small or a bit too large respectively... you hardly note them, when you zoom in, but by zooming out they get quite prominent. I suppose they are due to the fact, that the values of the levels are saved with low precision!? Is it possible to get rid of theese borders by some command?

I am aware that these borders will not make a difference in most applicative contexts. Unfortunately where I am using them the do not simply look ugly, but really disturb the quality of the depicted results...

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, colors=[[0,0,0.5],[0,0,0.2]])
plt.title('Saved as PNG')
plt.savefig('image1.png')

plt.title('Saved as SVG')
plt.savefig('image1.svg')
```

[image: saved as PNG]
[image: saved as SVG]

Comment: Can you please create a bug report on gh with this content (copy it please, links to SO will rot)?

Comment: never done that before, is it quite straight forward?

Comment: Yes, you will need a github account and then there is a bright green 'new issue' button.

Comment: I am going to do that than. So for the moment being most probably the only way of fixing the svg is via editing by hand with some vector graphics tool?

Answer (score 2):

I searched a long time for a fix of this. In [a github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4419#issuecomment-101253070) I found a fix for this:

```py
# ... setup code
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, colors=[[0,0,0.5],[0,0,0.2]])

for a in CS.collections:
    a.set_edgecolor("face")
```